# How to find the cause of delay?

Tags: linux, server, real-time, delay

A program I'm working on needs to process certain objects upon arrival from network in real-time. The throughput is good, but I have occasional drops in the input queue due to unexpected delays.

My analysis shows that most probably the source of the delay is outside my program; something like another process being scheduled on my process's CPU core (I set the affinity of the process to a certain core) or a hardware interrupt arriving (perhaps a network interrupt).

My problem is I don't know the source of the delay for sure. Is there a tool or a method to find how a CPU core was used exactly during a certain period of time? (Like for example telling me that core 0 was used by process 19494 99.1 percent of the time, process 20001 0.8 percent of the time and process 8110 0.1 percent of the time.)

I use Ubuntu 14.04 Server Edition on an HP server with a Xeon CPU.

Comment: Did you try increasing your program priority ?

Comment: Yes, I did that. I set the scheduling policy to FIFO and the priority to 99.

Comment: Can you try to run profiler and make sure the delay is external

Comment: A full profiler is a no-go in my situation. My reason for believing this delay is caused from outside is that the two parts of my program each exhibit reasonable delay when run independently. When put together though the delay is a lot more. My only guess so far had been a network interrupt (one of the two parts communicates with the network).

Comment: You could try to use Wireshark to check if the data arrives via the network or something happens during transmittion. I've seen a lot of stuff happening on networks which slowed my applications down (e.g. TCP/IP re-transmitts, ARP requests stalling TCP/IP stacks, ...).

Answer (score -1):

could be CPU, diskspeed, networkspeed or memory.

Memory usage and CPU is easy to spot using `htop` . (use the sort option, F6)

HD speed could be an issue. for example if you use low-energy disks (they slow down when not in use). Do you have a database running on the same system? 
use `iotop` , it might give a clue.

Comment: My program does not use the disk. No databases on the server either. I doubt htop can help me because the problem is not something obvious that can be spotted in htop. It's like a single context switch happens occasionally. That's why I want to find out what exactly is run on the CPU core during the lifetime of my program.

Comment: all processes show up using `top` or `htop`.  Or else use `ps aux | sort -k 3,3 ` during your process

Comment: I understand that. But they may show up so briefly that I don't notice them. Even if I do, I have no way of knowing for exactly how long.